# MingW Header Files Have No Labels

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-code, mingw, header-files

I've installed vscode extension (ms-vscode.cpptools) from Microsoft to enable intellisense. But, when i typed **MessageBox**, the parameters have no labels.

[image: Intellisense VSCode]

It should be

```
MessageBoxW(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
```

My Question: **Why MingW distribute the header files without labels?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should be

```
MessageBoxW(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
```

That is not so.

The tooltip is showing you the declaration of the function, as declared
in MingGW's header `winuser.h`. That declaration specifies the function's 
*prototype*, consisting of:

- The return type of the function, then
- The name of the function, then
- The types of the parameters in the parameter-list, within brackets, in the right order.

as the tooltip does:

```
int MessageBoxW (HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT)
```

What you call "labels" are parameter-names. They are optional, and redundant,
in a function declaration, since the compiler does not need them to understand
how the declared function will be called, and what it returns. `MessageBoxW`
is to be called with arguments that are a `HWND`, a `LPCSTR`, another `LPCSTR`,
and a `UINT`, in that order; and it returns and `int`.

The compiler requires parameters to be named in a function *definition*:

**add.c**

```
// definition

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int add(int,int); // Declaration

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",add(3,4));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with maximum strictness, link and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o prog main.c add.c
$ ./prog
7
```

See also [Function Declaration in C](https://syntaxdb.com/ref/c/function-dec)

Parameter-names are *useful* to human readers in a function-declaration when the declaration
is accompanied by documentation of the function, since the documentation
can then refer to the parameter-names to explain the function's behaviour:

```
/*
    Return the sum of `x` and `y`
*/
int add(int x, int y);
```

But they are unnecessary to the compiler.

Like the MinGW windows headers, Micorosoft's own headers do not contain comments
to document the APIs, but they *do* contain parameter-names, and also [SAL Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations?view=vs-2017)
of the parameter names. E.g. in Microsoft's `WinUser.h` (SDK 2017) the declaration of `MessageBoxW` is:

```
int
WINAPI
MessageBoxW(
    _In_opt_ HWND hWnd,
    _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpText,
    _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpCaption,
    _In_ UINT uType);
```

The SAL annotations, (`_In_opt_`, `_In_` and similar) are a non-standard Microsoft
language extension that supports static analysis of the correctness of code
implementing or invoking the APIs and they are used for that purpose by Microsoft's
compilers.

Such SAL-based static analysis needs *names* for the annotated parameters in order to provide
meaningful diagnostics; hence the parameters have names in the annotated declarations
in Microsoft's headers.

GCC, including MinGW ports, does not support SAL; so parameter names remain
redundant in function declarations.

Comment: Yes, i mean "parameter names". I'm just curious about MingW which didn't distribute the header files without parameter names like what Microsoft did. So i've to looking for the API documentations on the web.

Comment: @RizonBarns Hi. See extended answer.